# JxBrowser 6.12: Saved file does not appear

Tags: file, save, jxbrowser

Environment: Windows, Java-Application with JxBrowser control (Swing)

Since 6.12 we have the issue that a saved file does not appear in the target directory. The dialog opens, path can be choosen, but after hitting the save button, nothing happens.
There are no error messages.
This worked without problems with 6.8.

The file that should be saved is served by our java backend.

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like an issue in 6.12. Could you please try 6.11.1 version where this issue isn't reproducible while we are working on the fix.

Comment: @Vladimir: I got similar problem but when upload file in some website (I think the problem is about DialogHandler), you can try to login into gmail, click on the round button avatar on the right and try to upload a file to change google avatar.

Comment: This is a known issue in 6.12 that will be fixed in next update. Please subscribe to JxBrowser Release Notes web page to get notifications about new releases: https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/discussions/forums/9000110576

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. It seems that the location set by the method setDestinationFile() in class DownloadItem does not take effect and the file is always saved to the default location.

This problem does not appear in 6.11.1 version.

Hope my answer would help and looking forward to a solution.