# JxBrowser cannot upload file in version 6.12 & 6.13

Tags: jxbrowser

Go to gmail.com, click the avatar button and select a photo to upload but nothing happens! 6.9 is OK

I think this is similar to [JxBrowser 6.12: Saved file does not appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42093584/jxbrowser-6-12-saved-file-does-not-appear)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in 6.12 and 6.13. It is not reproducible in 6.11.1. Please consider using JxBrowser version 6.11.1 while we are working on the fix.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing you to let you know that the issue has been fixed. You can download EAP build with the fix from https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud.teamdev.com/downloads/jxbrowser/eap/jxbrowser-6.14-b13-eap-cross-desktop-win_mac_linux.zip

The fix will be included in official 6.14 release probably this month.

Comment: I'd like to inform you that we’ve just released JxBrowser 6.14 where the mentioned issue has been resolved. You can download it at https://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser